# Pentaho Report Designer HTML Table Alignment

Tags: html, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

please advice a way to align HTML table with Pentaho Report Designer (version 9.1), I've been using RichTextType = text/html, but can't find a way to align them like normal HTML.

[image: Here is the result from PRD]

Here is the HTML table's code :-

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 50%">Designation</th>
        <th style="width: 50%">Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%">Project Manager</td>
        <td style="width: 50%">Tester Tester 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%">Project Manager</td>
        <td style="width: 50%">Tester Tester 1</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance